# How to start/configure JBoss clustering

Tags: cluster-computing, jboss5.x, failovercluster

I am totally new to JBoss. Basically i am needed to setup a JBoss clustering environment on windows. Meaning, JBossA sits on machine A and JBossB sits on machine B. So when JBossA fails, it will redirect the clients to JBossB.

I have downloaded the enterprise-installer-5.0.1.jar. After which, I have totally no idea on how to go about setting up the cluster. What are the steps that i should do?? Or what other files do i need to download too...

Any guide will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Kevin

Comment: What sort of clients? HTTP? JMS?

Comment: Hmmm... there is no requirement for the client. Basically this environment is just for some testing purpose. So which ever HTTP/JMS is easier for the setting up of clustering, i think is fine.

Comment: Hi, At the JBoss EAP Admin Console, under the JBoss Cache/ha-partition, is there where i am supposed to do my clustering??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer... basically i just need to -c all to get the clustering